# Task with 'runner' not working as expected in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code 1.13.1, running in Windows Creator Update, I have defined this task in tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "runner": "terminal",
    "command": "echo",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["Hello world"],
    "showOutput": "always"
}
```

When I run the task I see this message in the integrated terminal:

> Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.

But I don't see "Hello world". Why?

Comment: Strange, that works fine for me (same VSCode and Windows version)... http://i.imgur.com/ZxJxtlm.png

Comment: Definitely doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you solved it yet, but I was having the same problem until I changed the terminal on settings.json from

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
```

to

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe"
```

If your settings.json file does not have this line you can add and see if the problem goes away.